# Angular.js app: eliminate #! from the URLs of my single posts while keeping the slug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute

I am working on a small AngularJS blogging app (the framework version I use is 1.7.8).

I have managed to pull and display posts from an API I made myself.

I got stuck trying to eliminate `#!` from the URLs of my single posts *while keeping the slug*.

Example:

I have `http://examplesite.eu/#!/europes-most-beautiful-castles` and I tried to get `http://examplesite.eu/europes-most-beautiful-castles`.

This solution from the AngularJS docs does not work, as it completely eliminates the slug, and I want to keep it, for SEO purposes:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

My app.js file:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'app.controllers',
    'ngSanitize'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsController'
    }).when('/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/singlepost.html',
        controller: 'SinglePostController'
    }).when('/page/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
        controller: 'PageController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

What's an alternative that would keep the slug in the post URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$locationProvider.html5mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#html5Mode) to switch over to the history api so that angular can manipulate the URL more directly rather than using hashes.

You can read more about it in the documentation [Hashbang and HTML5 Modes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

Comment: I have solved the problem in the manner described **[bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57668695/4512005)**.  However, removing `#!` causes thus error in the console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
this.location.replaceState(this.location.path().replace('#!/', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed clean-up the URLs by using the `$locationProvider`
 service:

My app.js file:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'app.controllers',
    'ngSanitize'
]).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsController'
    }).when('/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/singlepost.html',
        controller: 'SinglePostController'
    }).when('/page/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
        controller: 'PageController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
  });
}]);
```

In index.html I added `<base href="/">`:

```
<title>{{siteTitle}} | {{tagline}}</title>
<base href="/"> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```